# Vaciar un archivo .txt una vez que la informacion del archivo fue registrada en la base de datos en c#

Tags: c#

Necesito vaciar un `archivo.txt` o `archivo.csv` al momento de de guardar la información del archivo `.txt` o `.csv` en la base de datos.

Validar si el archivo csv existe y si no existe lo crea y guarda información.

```
string _arch = String.Format("{0}/{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RutaArchivo"], "respaldoActivaciones.csv");
StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(_arch);
writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", data["@IDAntena"], data["@Inicio"], data["@Termino"]));
writer.Close();
```

Pero esta información necesita ser borrada del archivo una vez que se guardó en la base de datos

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara, has intentado algo? Como se genera ese archivo? Pásate por [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. De todas maneras..has pensado en borrar el archivo una vez has transferido la información?

Comment: tengo una función donde creo un archivo y guardo datos en un archivo.csv y si no esta ese archivo en tal ruta crea el archivo. la información que se guarda en ese archivo se guarda cada 30 minutos en la base de datos sql server , pero necesito vaciar el archivo.csv porque ya se guardo en la base de datos..

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: deberias mostrar la funcion que ya tienes. y por vaciar a que te refieres??? a que quede en blanco? borrarlo?

Comment: Explica mejor lo que quieres lograr y pon algo del codigo que usas para generar el archivo y/o para guardar la info de dichos archivos en la base de datos

Comment: // Valida si el archivo csv existe y si no existe lo crea. y guarda informacion 
                string _arch = String.Format("{0}/{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RutaArchivo"], "respaldoActivaciones.csv");
                StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(_arch);
                writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", data["@IDAntena"], data["@Inicio"], data["@Termino"]));
                writer.Close();   // PERO ESTA INFORMACION NECESITA SER BORRA DEL ARCHIVO UNA VEZ QUE SE GUARDO EN LA BASE DE DATOS

Comment: por favor agrega tu comentario a la pregunta para que quede claro que es lo que tenes.

Answer (score 2):

Para eliminar el contenido de un archivo utiliza [`System.IO.File.WriteAllText(text)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
  string _arch = System.IO.Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RutaArchivo"], "respaldoActivaciones.csv");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(_arch, String.Empty);
```